# How to fetch data from One To One Relationship in SubQuery using Hibernate in spring

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

I have two table `hesk_users`, `user` as under.

@Entity
@Table(name="hesk_users")
public class UserHesk {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column
private int id;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="user_id")
private User user;

    set.... get..
```

}

@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User implements Serializable {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

@NotEmpty
@Column
private String firstname;

     @OneToOne(mappedBy="user")
private UserHesk userHesk; 

    set ... get ...
```

}

I have hibernate query but it not working..

```
            DetachedCriteria detachedCriteria=DetachedCriteria.forClass(UserHesk.class)
    .setProjection(Projections.property("user_id"));

    Criteria criteria=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(User.class);
    criteria.add(Property.forName("id").notIn(detachedCriteria));
    User user=(User)criteria.list().get(0);
    System.out.println(user.getFirstname());
    System.out.println("Subquery Size "+criteria.list().size());
```

Error for `user_id` filed. which can not be get because of relationship.

Answer (score 0):

HQL and criteria queries always use the entity classes and properties. Never the names of the underlying tables and columns. The UserHesk class doesn't have any `user_id` property. It has a `user` property.

So the code should be

```
DetachedCriteria detachedCriteria = 
    DetachedCriteria.forClass(UserHesk.class)
                    .setProjection(Projections.property("user.id"));
```

or even

```
DetachedCriteria detachedCriteria = 
    DetachedCriteria.forClass(UserHesk.class)
                    .createAlias("user", "u")
                    .setProjection(Projections.property("u.id"));
```

Comment: I wont criteria on colunm user_id that is generated using OneToOne Relationship. I do not have set and get mathod for the userId colunm.